# calling javascript Object from ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I want to instantiate a class in javascript, pass the object over to my ClojureScript, and access its properties and functions from Clojure. How can I access the functions and properties of test-obj when I only have clojure.core namespace at my disposal?

I have the following awful hacked solution.

Javascript:

```
class Test {
  constructor (a,b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  getA () {
    return this.a;
  }
}

window['createA'] = (a,b) => {
  return new Test(a,b);
}

window['geta'] = (o) => {
  return o.getA();
}
```

ClojureScript:

```
(defn myfn[] 
  (let [test-obj (.createTest js/window "x" 1)]
  [:div (.geta js/window test-obj)]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular JS interop should work just fine I believe :)

Expose your class to the outside world:

```
window["Test"] = Test
```

Then, from cljs:

```
(let [x (js/Test.)]
  (prn (.getA x)))
```